# SQLite Conditional SUM

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I would like to do how to make a conditional SUM in SQLite. I've created this example :

**TABLE BEFORE SQL ACTION**

```
   ID1   ID2   Value   TOTAL
-------------------------------
    1                   None
          1     7.00    None
          1     1.00    None
          1     1.00    None
          1     3.00    None
          1     2.00    None
    2                   None
          2     5.00    None
          2     1.00    None
    3                   None
          3     7.00    None
          3     1.00    None
          3     1.00    None
          3     3.00    None
```

The above table is the data without any modification yet. I want to make a SUM of the value if the ID1 = ID2 and post the result into the 'TOTAL' column.

**TABLE AFTER SQL ACTION**

```
   ID1   ID2   Value   TOTAL
-------------------------------
    1                   14.00
          1     7.00    None
          1     1.00    None
          1     1.00    None
          1     3.00    None
          1     2.00    None
    2                   6.00
          2     5.00    None
          2     1.00    None
    3                   12.00
          3     7.00    None
          3     1.00    None
          3     1.00    None
          3     3.00    None
```

I've tried this with no success :

```
curOperations.execute('UPDATE TABLE1 SET TOTAL = 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as Value FROM TABLE1)')
```

---

**EDIT**

So I've found a way to obtain the SUM quite easily :

```
SELECT ID2, SUM(Value) FROM Table GROUP BY ID2
```

With that I obtain this table :

```
   ID2   SUM(Value)
------------------------
    1       14.00
    2       6.00
    3       12.00
```

The only thing I have to do now is to pass these values to the 'main' table

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must use an update with a subquery - the only tricky part is that the alias must be on the subquery:

```
curOperations.execute('''UPDATE table1 SET total = (SELECT SUM(value)
    FROM table1 int
    WHERE int.id2 = table1.id1)
    WHERE id1 IS NOT NULL''')
```

Comment: @CL. This query only updates row having a non null ID1, and give the values you show in your *TABLE AFTER SQL ACTION* display.

Comment: The UPDATE modifies all rows, even those where the subquery returns NULL.